# get (pubg, freefire, jawaker) player name by id

Tags: api, mobile, pubg

i have website for mobile games services
i need api for (get player name by his ID in each game)
the games ( pubg, freefire, jawaker . . .)
i know that there is no official api for any of this games
but at the same time this (api or service) is exist
and i saw it in some websites

so can anyone tell me how to do this given that there is no official api ??

Answer (score 0):

If you provided that website you can track the requests that's going out and in from the page using Developer tool network

**Checkout this:** https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-find-the-api-of-a-website/